# User access management for Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

My question is related to "**Multiple User Accounts**" feature of **Developer Console** of **Google Play Store**. 
I want to give access of only few applications to secondary users and he should not be able to see all apps. Like i have say 3 apps "A", "B" and "C". I want to hide apps "A" and "B" from the secondary user.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691?hl=en

It says **Users can be given access to all applications, or specific applications**.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link.. although articles says what i need but it is not working :( .. so vote up for answer :)